# Mechanics Polar Coordinates Question (Circular Motion)

Tags: polar-coordinates, classical-mechanics

Whilst learning about polar coordinates on circular motion, I had come across this question,

> 'A particle moves along a curve with polar equation $ r\theta = a$ (for $\theta \geq \frac{\pi}{4}$) in such a way that the transverse component of the acceleration is always zero. Show that the radial component of the acceleration is inversely proportional to $r^3$'

My current workings out:

Let the transverse component of acceleration be $\alpha_{\theta} = 2\dot{r}\dot{\theta} + \ddot{\theta}$.

Differentiating $r\theta = a$ with respect to time,

$$ \frac{d(r\theta)}{dt} = \frac{d(a)}{dt}$$
Because $a$ is a constant, $a = 0$,
$$ \dot{r}\theta + \dot{\theta}r = 0 $$

Differentiating again for a second time with the product rule,

$$ \ddot{r}\theta + \dot{\theta}\dot{r} + \ddot{\theta}r + \dot{r}\dot{\theta} = 0 $$

Rearrange for $\ddot{\theta}$,

$$\ddot{\theta} = \frac{-2\dot{r}\dot{\theta} - \ddot{r}\theta}{r} $$

Making $\alpha_{\theta} = 0 $,

$$ 2\dot{r}\dot{\theta} + \ddot{\theta} = 0 $$

Substituting in $\ddot{\theta}$ leads to,

$$-\ddot{r}\theta = 0 $$

From here, I am not sure where to go. I have tried using this with the radial component of acceleration but got not much luck. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: When you rearranged for $\ddot \theta$ you dropped the factor of $2$ on the $\dot r \dot \theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transverse acceleration is $$\frac 1r\frac{d}{dt}(r^2\dot{\theta})=0\implies r^2\dot{\theta}=k$$

Now$$r\theta=a\implies\theta=\frac ar\implies \dot{\theta}=-\frac{a}{r^2}\dot{r}$$

Combining these results gives $$\dot{r}=-\frac ka\implies\ddot{r}=0$$

The radial component of acceleration is $$\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2$$
$$=0-r\left(\frac{k}{r^2}\right)$$

And hence the result

Comment: How did you obtain the first line? I'm not sure where you got that from.

Comment: It is a standard expression for the transverse acceleration, and is equivalent to $2\dot{r}\dot{\theta}+r\ddot{\theta}$. The expression you started with is incorrect.